# ubuntu grinds to halt

Tags: unity, 14.10

Oftentimes, my new laptop (Yoga 2 Pro with 256GB SSD with >30GB free, Quadcore i7 processor, 8GB ram) grinds to a halt, to the point where it does not even respond to `ctrl-alt-t` for a terminal (to `xkill` them all). Unfortunately, I cannot reliably reproduce the situation, but part of it seems to be related to the copying of files. (see edits below)

When checking the system monitor, CPU and memory are only at a few %. My OS is ubuntu linux 14.10 unity.

What could be the cause here, or how do I find that out? Is there some system diagnostics tool I could use? Other than the system monitor / `top`, I wouldn't know where to start.

I'm sorry I cannot give more useful information at this point.

### EDIT

It's again come to complete standstill, and I can report the following:

- again, low CPU load of <10% at each core
- again, apparent low (1.8GB out of 7.7GB) ram usage

I've run `free -h` and the output is this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7,7G       7,6G       168M       721M       1,7G       4,0G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1,8G       5,9G
Swap:         7,9G         0B       7,9G
```

The ram seems almost full, although www.linuxatemyram.com insists this is not an issue.
Swap is not being used at all.

Some more information:

1. The slowdown seemed to start as soon as I started copying data over wifi to a NAS via NFS. Might this be the cause? If so; what should I change? I initiated the copying with an `rsync` command this time, though last time the same problems occurred I had simply drag&dropped in KDE dolphin.
2. After about 5 long minutes, the data transfer was still going on, but the system resumed to be responsive. For what it's worth, running `free -h` again now showed that Swap *was* used, be it only marginally:

   ```
                total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   Mem:          7,7G       7,4G       373M       742M       1,2G       4,4G
   -/+ buffers/cache:       1,8G       5,9G
   Swap:         7,9G        24K       7,9G
   ```

It was suggested to "dump the cache" by @Charles Green (in comments), but I do not know how that's done.

### EDIT 2

After having let the laptop copy files throughout the night, it has now completely hung itself up. I can *move* the mouse, but it's not reacting to clicking or the keyboard - so I cannot open a terminal - and the clock is frozen to 4h ago.

Here's a video for the more visually inclined: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0be9f2aflamjap4/2014-12-11%2008.00.34.mp4?dl=0

I'm really scratching my head here, any help is very appreciated!

### EDIT 3

Not sure if this is related, but trying to open a 160kB file with gedit is now warming up CPU and having the fans blowing. System is still responsive though. As requested, the top few lines from `top`:

```
top - 01:10:20 up  1:37,  2 users,  load average: 1,45, 2,93, 2,71
Tasks: 282 total,   2 running, 260 sleeping,   0 stopped,  20 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27,0 us,  0,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 72,6 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   8090584 total,  7877924 used,   212660 free,  1660296 buffers
KiB Swap:  8301564 total,    39104 used,  8262460 free.  3931712 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 7390 ruud      20   0  726792  39320  29932 R 100,1  0,5   0:22.94 gedit       
 3305 ruud      20   0 1764168 525388  76496 S   3,7  6,5  13:46.52 firefox     
 1362 root      20   0  433912 104068  79424 S   2,7  1,3   7:01.56 Xorg        
 5053 ruud      20   0 1525584 124012  51876 S   1,7  1,5   5:56.92 plugin-con+ 
 7190 ruud      20   0  673584  31424  24532 S   1,3  0,4   0:01.49 gnome-term+ 
 2815 ruud      20   0 1667352 219868  53380 S   1,0  2,7   4:19.10 compiz
```

Had to kill `gedit` eventually; with `nano` the file opened in no-time. Again, not sure if this is related.

### Edit 4

Copying files from USB connected HD to USB connected HD, system becomes unresponsive:

```
top - 18:14:04 up 21:31,  9 users,  load average: 3,98, 4,06, 4,12
Tasks: 452 total,   2 running, 261 sleeping,   0 stopped, 189 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7,7 us,  7,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 35,6 id, 48,4 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,5 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   8090584 total,  7921160 used,   169424 free,  2608348 buffers
KiB Swap:  8301564 total,   188852 used,  8112712 free.  2113508 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND          
16500 root      20   0   14892   3468   1688 D  32,6  0,0  19:46.72 mount.ntfs       
16508 ruud      20   0  240968  54468  15672 S  17,6  0,7  11:51.53 kio_file         
 1332 root      20   0  447012 127224  80296 S   7,3  1,6  47:07.78 Xorg             
16718 ruud      20   0  815636 109708  51688 D   5,3  1,4  11:55.43 plugin-containe  
 2183 ruud      20   0 1333696 137256  49404 S   5,0  1,7  32:56.98 compiz
```

### Edit 5

Again, this time with no particular action having been started by the user. What is `ibus`?

```
top - 14:18:44 up  2:16,  2 users,  load average: 4.25, 1.62, 0.64
Tasks: 224 total,   2 running, 222 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 73.2 us,  6.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 20.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8090584 total,  4064852 used,  4025732 free,   125548 buffers
KiB Swap:  8301564 total,        0 used,  8301564 free.  1438224 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 2376 ruud      20   0  400792  61056   5548 S 113.4  0.8   1:25.79 ibus-daemon 
 3329 ruud      20   0 1684160 649336  93528 R 110.4  8.0  11:22.34 firefox     
 2411 ruud      20   0 1138788 761352  22168 S  69.8  9.4   0:32.86 ibus-ui-gt+ 
 2460 ruud      20   0  225244  60104   5580 S  16.0  0.7   0:12.19 ibus-engin+
```

Comment: You could try `sar` and `psacct` but I'd start by looking at the cpu frequency options under power management.

Comment: As you run your computer during the day, can you occasionally look at `free -h` and determine if the swap is being used?  My Dell laptop w/o SSD has some odd problem when the cache is quite full, and behaves in a manner similar to what you describe.  I dumpt the cache, and push all the swap back into RAM and everything is fine again.

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait for the problems to reoccur, but to make sure I'm ready, (1) `sar` (after installing `sysstat`) says `Cannot open /var/log/sysstat/sa10: No such file or directory. Please check if data collecting is enabled`. (2) `psacct` and `acct` say `No command xxx found, did you mean:` with some suggestions. (3) `free -h` shows that more Mem is used than what is shown in the System Monitor; the additional 2.5GB is distributed over `shared`, `buffers`, and `cached`. Right now, Swap is empty.
(#####) Comments on any of these points are very welcome.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I thought I'd mention it nonetheless: before running `apt-get update` (which I've done many times before), I couldn't install anything. `apt-get install sysstat`, for example, gave `Package sysstat is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.`, which I've never seen before. I guess it might be caused by a system crash after which some lists need to be rebuild, but this is pure speculation from my part.

Comment: It could be a badly implemented module that is causing too high IOwait and then your CPU is just being wasted...
Additional needed info: Does it only happen when copying files over WiFi or also disk?  When this happens again, can you also provide the top 5 lines of `top`?

Comment: @Fabby - thanks for your comment; I just edited the question to include some more info. This particular time it happened while opening a file right on the SSD while no other file transfers were taking place.

Comment: IMHO not related.  I've had the same with gedit if the file contains binary data... Can you replace the top output of what you saw earlier? (FTP or SCP or something?)

Comment: Alright, thanks for your perspective. I'll put the `top` output as soon as I have another hang-up

Comment: The hang-up is currently occurring; see my edit 4

Comment: ... and again, edit 5.